# What is the random code set in the middle of a URL?

Tags: python, url

I have a URL: http://www.cbonline.co.uk/resources/b63662d3-b27b-4239-821d-844d74ee51f8/something.xls, and I need to download the file from it automatically by Python 2.7. That means I need to reconstruct the URL when the file that URL pointin to is updated.

For the file name part, it is fairly simple, I can make it `...something else.xls`

However, in the middle of it, there is a fragment `/b63662d3-b27b-4239-821d-844d74ee51f8/` and I don't know what it is or how should I construct it.

Anyone has any idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an UUID - a random unique ID for the file in question. Basically: you either have that number from some other source (usually an API endpoint, or an HTML page witha listing and links) or you can't have the URL.